# hbaseTemplate get after a put doesn't work with autoFlush on

Tags: java, hbase

I am doing a put using hbaseTemplate with the autoFlush property set to true (it's default) and it works fine. However when I do a put and a get right away in code I don't get my object back :(

put function

```
    hbaseTemplate.execute(tableName, new TableCallback<Object>() 
    {
        @Override
        public Object doInTable(HTableInterface table) throws IOException
        {
            if (contact.getContactID() == null)
            {
                contact.setContactID(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            }

            Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(contact.getCompositeKey()));

            if (contact.getFirstName() != null) {
                put.add(columnFamilyName, firstName, Bytes.toBytes(contact.getFirstName()));
            }

            if (contact.getLastName() != null) {
                put.add(columnFamilyName, lastName, Bytes.toBytes(contact.getLastName()));
            }

            if (contact.getContactID() != null) {
                put.add(columnFamilyName, contactID, Bytes.toBytes(contact.getContactID()));
            }

            table.put(put);

            return null;
        }
    });
```

Get function

```
public UserContact getContactByContactId(String contactId) 
{
    Scan scan = new Scan();
    String criteria = contactId;

    Filter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(columnFamilyName, contactID, CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, 
                                                new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes(criteria)));
    scan.setFilter(filter);

    UserContact contact = null;

    contact = hbaseTemplate.find(tableName, scan, new ResultsExtractor<UserContact>() {

        @Override
        public UserContact extractData(ResultScanner resultScanner) throws Exception 
        {
            Result result = resultScanner.next();

            return loadContact(result);

        }
    });
```

And then on the client side all I do is

```
String contactId = "somerandomid";
UserContact contact = new UserContact();
contact.setContactId(contactId);
repo.put(contact);
UserContact c = repo.getContactByContactId(contactId);
// here c is null :(
```

however using the shell I can see that the contact was added fine ...